# intellij: errors with scala, spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I have a scala project using spark libraies, and it works fine most of the times(using intellij). But some times it starts giving errors on intellij launch:

```
    [warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
    [error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last update' for the full output
    [error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last ssExtractDependencies' for the full output
    [error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:3.0.0-preview2
    [error]   Not found
    [error]   Not found
    [error]   not found: C:\...\.ivy2\localorg.apache.spark\spark-core_2.12\3.0.0-preview2\ivys\ivy.xml
    [error]   checksum format error: C:\....\AppData\Local\Coursier\Cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\apache\spark\spark-core_2.12\3.0.0-preview2\.spark-core_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.pom__sha1
    [error]   checksum format error: C:\....\AppData\Local\Coursier\Cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\apache\spark\spark-core_2.12\3.0.0-preview2\.spark-core_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.pom__sha1
    [error] Error downloading org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:3.0.0-preview2
    [error]   Not found
    [error]   Not found
    [error]   not found: C:\...\.ivy2\localorg.apache.spark\spark-sql_2.12\3.0.0-preview2\ivys\ivy.xml
    [error]   checksum format error: C:\....\AppData\Local\Coursier\Cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\apache\spark\spark-sql_2.12\3.0.0-preview2\.spark-sql_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.pom__sha1
    [error] (ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:3.0.0-preview2
    [error]   Not found
    [error]   Not found
    [error]   not found: C:\...\.ivy2\localorg.apache.spark\spark-core_2.12\3.0.0-preview2\ivys\ivy.xml
    [error]   checksum format error: C:\....\AppData\Local\Coursier\Cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\apache\spark\spark-core_2.12\3.0.0-preview2\.spark-core_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.pom__sha1
    [error] Error downloading org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:3.0.0-preview2
    [error]   Not found
    [error]   Not found
    [error]   not found: C:\...\.ivy2\localorg.apache.spark\spark-sql_2.12\3.0.0-preview2\ivys\ivy.xml
    [error]   checksum format error: C:\....\AppData\Local\Coursier\Cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\apache\spark\spark-sql_2.12\3.0.0-preview2\.spark-sql_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.pom__sha1
    [error] Total time: 1 s, completed 17 Sep 2022, 15:13:49
    [info] shutting down sbt server
```

build.sbt is:

```
/*ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.8"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "spark-learning"
  )*/

// Name of the package
name := "spark-learning"
// Version of our package
version := "1.0"
// Version of Scala
scalaVersion := "2.12.14"
// Spark library dependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.0-preview2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.0-preview2"
)
```

What causes these issues out of sudden?And how can I get rid?

Comment: Not related but you should probably use latest Spark release rather than a version "preview"

Answer (score 0):

One weird thing in the error messages is the path where it looks for dependencies: `...ivy2\localorg.apache.spark\...`.

There should be a `\` after `local`.

Any chance your SBT repositories configuration could be messed up? Not sure where it is on Windows, it's `/etc/sbt/repositories` typically on Linux but maybe Intellij has its own setting.

Comment: Spark dependencies are at .../AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\apache\spark. Not sure why it looks somewhere else.